# Find program is installed or not

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program that needs to see if a particular program is
installed (it would be listed in the "Add or Remove Programs" list from the
Control Panel) and uninstall it.
Is there a way to do this?.. Thanks for any help...

they already installed the application... here my need is whether it's avalable in add or programes...

Comment: Are you using a windows installer to install your application? If yes then you can give prerequisites to your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can check windows registry at [**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**]

There are two important values you can use:

- **DisplayName**: Name of the program
- **UninstallString**: command to be executed to uninstall the program. This might be handy for you to uninstall the application.

Generally all the programs does have their custom registry settings and its better to use them. IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" keys and check their "DisplayName" value for the name of that program.